# Unable to Deserialize an Object from a Plugin

Tags: java, reflection, deserialization

My java application has a plugin architecture whereby its functionality can be extended by adding a jar file that implements its plugin interface.  I have successfully used and deployed this architecture in the past.  This time, however, I am trying to serialize/de-serialize plugin objects from the main application.

Loading the plugin works just fine.  The test application can even use it.

Serializing the object works just fine too (at least, it appears to).  An object is written to disk.

When I attempt to de-serialize the object, ClassNotFound is thrown. Even when done in the same application as discovering the plugin and serializing the object (i.e. the class should already be by one of the class loaders).

I wrote a single test application that loads the plugin (loads the jar file and all of the classes in it), creates an instance of the plugin object, serializes the plugin object, and then attempts to deserialize the object into a new object (where it fails).

The failure occurs on the:

```
Class.forName(...)
```

call that is within readObject().

I have even implemented a custom ObjectInputStream that uses the same ClassLoader as the class that loads the plugin and this still doesn't work.

Am I breaking some Java rule that I don't know about?
Other than in-theory, is this even possible?
Any other ideas?

Comment: Object serialization is a poor choice of the long term storage of objects, something like JAXB would be better.  Having said that, in what class loader context is the object been serialised/deserialized in?  Does the class exist within the class loader context?

Comment: How are you serializing?

Comment: Serializing using ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: Understand this is not ideal...this is the first implementation just to get it working.  As for the context, this is a URLClassLoader that all plugins use.  I had to implement this in order to allow the class loader to remember other JARs that other plugins have loaded.

Comment: Okay, it is working now.  The solution was the custom ObjectInputStream.  It didn't appear to work because the code kept crashing on the forName() that I was using to test the code.  Aside from an imperfect implementation (object serialization), it is now working.  Thanks for the help and information!